# We have UI which is driven by APIs. We have UI automation tests which covers all major functionalities. Do we need to still test apis?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, rest-assured

Our UI is developed using API driven. Using Spring/Springboot for backend, while angular for front end. We have developed only UI tests which covers major functionalities of the application. Do we need to script API tests as well?

Comment: If something is broken in the API do you want to investigate the UI first to discover that it's the API's fault?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have API tests as a part of testing.

Automating API tests along with the UI tests is highly beneficial.
They provide independent validation of backend functionality, ensure comprehensive test coverage, enable faster and more efficient testing, provides in early issue detection, facilitate integration testing.

[REST-assured](https://rest-assured.io/) is the best tool for API automation.